# Concat in ExactTarget - SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Could you help me with adding a field to a table that concatenates two strings, please ? As there is no CONCAT in ET this doesn't work

```
SELECT NameID, EmailAddress, CONCAT(CONVERT(varchar, GetUtcDate(), 101), '_CampaignCode') as CampaignCode
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String concatenation in Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget) Query activities works just like T-SQL

```
SELECT NameID, EmailAddress, (CONVERT(varchar, GetUtcDate(), 101) +  '_CampaignCode') as CampaignCode
```

Comment: Brilliant. I wasn't aware of this. How about adding columns? I've tried using ALTER TABLE but no luck again

Comment: Query Activities are only for select statement.  Any modification to the structure of a Data Extension like adding columns will need to done using the UI or SOAP API.